# I'm noticing that Azure functions seem to not preserve the value of `this` for use with prototypal inheritance

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure

I'm noticing that Azure functions seem to not preserve the value of `this` for use with prototypal inheritance. Logging the value of `this` within the body of a method defined on a constructor function's prototype returns `undefined`. Just wondering whether this is normal and intended behavior in an Azure function. I'm also wondering whether there's a way around it, because not having access to prototype inheritance is lame.

Edit: Here's a bit more information.

I'm importing a Node module which IS a constructor function and instantiating an instance of that function from within my Azure function (which happens to be a timer trigger, incidentally). In that module, I define the constructor function's method on its prototype. The problem is that Azure doesn't seem to be respecting prototypal inheritance and is losing reference to `this`, which returns `undefined`.

Edit 2 (Code):

poll.js

```
const Poll = function () {...};

Poll.prototype.getUnprocessedCandidates = function () {...};

Poll.prototype._getUnprocessedCandidates = function () {
    let self = this;
    self._filterProcessedCandidates();
};
```

Timer Trigger

```
'use strict';

const Poll = require('./poll');

module.exports = function (context, candidateQueueTimer) {
  let poll = new Poll();

  poll.pollForCandidates(context)
  .then(poll.getUnprocessedCandidates)      
  .then(() => { context.done(); })
  .catch(error => context.done(error));
};
```

^ PLEASE ignore the arguments being passed, etc. They don't bear on the matter at all.

I should mention that I'm using the Node Azure Functions package in Windows. (I'm actually dual-developing this application, primarily on a Mac and then actually executing the functions in a Windows environment.) When I log the value of `this` from within the body of the "public" getUnprocessedCandidates method (Poll.prototype.getUnprocessedCandidates), the output appears to be some sort of Azure function object.

Comment: that makes it not a Constructor, but you can call()/apply()/bind() it anyway

Comment: Well, I should clarify. I'm importing a Node module which IS a constructor function. In that module, I define the constructor function's method on its prototype. The problem is that Azure doesn't seem to be respecting prototypal inheritance and is losing reference to `this`, which returns `undefined`.

Comment: How is the method defined on the constructor function's prototype property being invoked?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this with me. I'm going to answer above the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Functions wouldn't prevent prototypal inheritance from working. For example, the following works:

```
var Foo = function(timeStamp, context) {
    this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
    this.context = context;
};

Foo.prototype.speak = function(context) {
    this.context.log(this.timeStamp);
}

module.exports = function (context, myTimer) {
    var timeStamp = new Date().toISOString();

    var foo = new Foo(timeStamp, context);
    foo.speak();

    context.done();
};
```

Are you handing off a reference to the method without using bind?